# App data security on jailbroken iPhones

Tags: iphone, security

If I'm not mistaken (and if I am mistaken, here or in what I say below, please correct me), non-jailbroken iPhones provide two broad areas of storage space:

- for apps (and data that comes bundled with apps);
- for user-managed files.

I understand that the former is protected storage, meaning that data bundled with an app and stored in that area is not accessible to the user except via the app.

On a jailbroken iPhone, does this protected area still exist? If so, what protections remain; i.e. is data stored within it still inaccessible to the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a jailbroken iPhone the user has full access to all resources.  The user will have more control over the device than any developer.  There is no place to hide secrets on the device, even memory is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Even on a non-Jailbroken phone it's easy to extract the user data from the backups that iTunes creates when the user syncs (unless the user specifically enables the "encrypt backups" option).

The apps themselves are nominally encrypted using iTunes DRM, but since you can download apps in iTunes on a desktop and (AIUI) easily remove the DRM, again, even users without jailbroken devices can access your resources.

Comment: But some directories (like Caches) are specifically not backed up, and so not browsable that way.

Comment: The "usual" way to strip DRM is to do a memory-dump of the binary while it's running (i.e. after it's been decrypted); I'm not sure how difficult obtaining the key used to encrypt it is (it can be more tightly controlled because it never has to leave the phone).

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards:

- Third-party apps are sandboxed so they cannot access "protected" data, including some system data and other apps' data.
- System apps tend to not be sandboxed and have extra privileges (they might all do). For example, App Store has to be able to upgrade other apps, and exploiting holes through Safari was one way to root a phone (suggesting Safari runs as root).

**Nowhere is app data protected from the user.** Instead, Apple apps do not expose the filesystem (and third-party apps can only expose a small portion of it).

Additionally, the "two areas of storage" are actually / (more or less the firmware image) and /var/mobile (more or less the user data partition). AIUI, upgrading the OS overwrites / but leaves /var/mobile intact; this is how a normal upgrade manages to preserve all your data without a long backup/restore process. IIRC, system apps are in /Applications and third-party apps are installed to /var/mobile/Applications.

I'm not sure what category Apple apps distributed on the App Store fall under (iBooks, Remote, Pages/Numbers/etc).